# How to do client to client routing rules with UFW?

Tags: iptables, ufw, wireguard

I would like to use UFW to control client to client access rules for a wireguard network.  And I would like to do this on a central hub server. But I can't quite figure it out. Right now it works but everybody can access everything.

UFW seems to be really good at controlling access to a host. But how can it control what routes though? Do I have to resort to iptables instead?

Is part of my problem that the traffic is entering and leaving by the same wg0 interface?

e.g. I would like to implement something like this. Hub server is 10.0.0.1, all clients use 10.0.0.0/24, etc.

```
ufw allow 10.0.0.2 to 10.0.0.3 on port 80
ufw allow 10.0.0.4 to 10.0.0.5 on port 3389
ufw deny all to 10.0.0.0/24
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with ufw using the `route` keyword. Something like the following would be equivalent to the rules you mentioned in your question:

```
ufw route allow to 10.0.0.3 port 80 proto tcp from 10.0.0.2
ufw route allow to 10.0.0.5 port 3389 proto tcp from 10.0.0.4
ufw route deny to 10.0.0.0/24
```

Note, however, that any iptables rules you already have added may override your ufw rules. Run `sudo iptables-save` to see your list of existing itables rules -- every rule that ufw adds to iptables (and they'll be a lot) will include `ufw` somewhere in the rule. Rules listed first take precedence, so if you have some non-ufw rules listed before your ufw rules (ie you have a line that begins with `-A` but doesn't contain `ufw` in it), they may override what you've configured ufw to do.

Comment: I missed that. Thanks. I am now messing around with nftables which may be better suited to this scenario... Though it might not automate as easily.